# How to encode a TAB character in a Code128 barcode using only raw ZPL

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii, code128

In the past, we've used ZPL to create Code39 barcodes with a TAB character encoded in the middle using something similar to the following:

```
*USERNAME$IPASSWORD*
```

The $I in the middle gets translated to a TAB by the barcode scanners we use.

Now we have a need to do the same thing, but using Code128.  With Code39, all the text needs to be uppercase (unless you're using Code39Extended, which supports lowercase letters).  Because some of the data that is going to be encoded will be lowercase, we need to use Code128 B for most of the barcode, switching to Code128 A in the middle to encode the TAB character, then back to Code128 B for the final part.

Looking through the "ZPL II Programming Guide", it should be as easy as:

```
>:username>7{TAB}>6PA55w0rd
```

The >: at the beginning sets the subset to B, the >7 changes the subset to A, and the >6 changes the subset back to B.  The problem I'm having (and haven't found a solution after almost a week of searching) is: How do I encode a TAB character using only text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried what [Mark Warren](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70776412/697520) suggested, but unfortunately, it didn't work.  It did, however, get me looking back through the *ZPL II Programming Guide* and I found the following, which I had overlooked before:

```
Code 128, Subsets A and C are programmed in pairs of digits, 00 to 99, in the field data string.
...
In Subset A, each pair of digits results in a single character being encoded in the bar code...
```

So, since 73 equates to a TAB in Subset A, I tried the following:

```
>:username>773>6PA55w0rd
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `^FH` (field hexidecimal encoding) command immediately prior to your field data.  Based on your example:

```
^FH_^FD>:username>7_09>6PA55w0rd^FS
```

Where the underscore '_' is used as the escape character and 09 is the hex value for tab.

Also note that if the chosen escape character appears in the user name or password, you will need to escape it as well.